# Apache POI excel how to apply text top left indent for a cell

Tags: apache-poi, alignment, indentation

How can I add top left indent with left text alignment in Apache POI?

What I currently have :

```
 private CellStyle setDateAndTimeCellStyle(XSSFWorkbook workbook, Font font) {

    CellStyle dateCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    dateCellStyle.setWrapText(true);
    dateCellStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT);
    dateCellStyle.setIndention(CellStyle.VERTICAL_TOP);
    dateCellStyle.setFont(font);
    dateCellStyle.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    dateCellStyle.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    dateCellStyle.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    return dateCellStyle;
}

CellStyle dateCellStyle = setDateAndTimeCellStyle(workbook, font);
```

Comment: What ancient `apache poi` version are you using? The constants in `CellStyle` were removed in version `3.17`. Current version is `4.1.1`. And `CellStyle.setIndention(short indent)` never was thougth using a constant but sets the number of spaces to indent the text in the cell. The parameter `indent` gives the number of spaces to indent from left. Indentation from top is not possible as far as I know. How would you do this in `Excel`'s `GUI`?

Comment: I'm using version 3.0.2. There is an option in Excel GUI to set the indentation to top, center or bottom. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Whow version `3.0.2`. You also are still using `Windows 3.11`, are you? But since version `3.0.2` does not even have a class `CellStyle`, I doubt that. And I suspect you mean the vertical alignment instead of indentation: `CellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_TOP);`, `CellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);`, `CellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_BOTTOM);` or `CellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_JUSTIFY);`.

Comment: Correction, the version is 4.0.1

Comment: In `apache poi 4.0.1` your showed code could not compile. There are no `CellStyle.VERTICAL_*` constants anymore. There is [CellStyle.setVerticalAlignment](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setVerticalAlignment-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.VerticalAlignment-) having [VerticalAlignment](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/VerticalAlignment.html) as the align parameter.

Comment: Okay.. I want to make it top left indented. without any alignment

Comment: How would you do this in `Excel`'s `GUI`?

Comment: Sorry. I think i have misinterpreted the word. I need the text to be left and top aligned. No indentation.

Comment: `CellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.TOP);` and `CellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);`